# Need to stop printing Counter() after a certain amount of items have been printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write a program that prints the *n* most common items in a list depending on how many the user wants to see, and prints more if the last items have the same frequency.

This is what i have written:

```
num = int(input("Enter Number"))
i = 0
wordsInList = [word1, word2, word2, word3, word1]
catagory = Counter(list)
catagory.keys()
for key, value in catagory.items(): #set the frequency to value and word to key
    if i <= num or lastValue == value: #(Issue with code)If the required number of values have been printed, stop printing
        print('{:<5d}{:<15s}'.format(value, key)) 
        lastValue = value
        i =+ 1
```

The problem with this is that as soon as that print statement is run, it prints all lines of the *count()*.

Example would be if the user only wanted to print the most common value:

```
n = 1
```

most common value would be a tie between *word1* and *word2* - as they both appear twice. So the output would be

```
2  word1
2  word2
```

If the user was to enter *n = 2*, the output would be the same, as they are the 2 most common words. However if the user entered *n=3*, below would be the output:

```
2  word1
2  word2
1  word3
```

Comment: Please post an example with a sample input and desired outcome.

Comment: @musikreck Done

Comment: Note that the licensing conditions here that you've agreed to by posting explicitly allow the community to keep your question in a good state. We're a bit like Wikipedia, in that we want the best possible version of each question, and we always roll back vandalism.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach :

```
n = 3
sorted_dict_list = sorted(category.items(), key = lambda x:x[1], reverse = True) 
last_value = sorted_dict_list[0][1]
for key, value in sorted_dict_list:
    if (value == last_value - n):
        break
    print("{},{}".format(value, key))
```

Comment: Error in that lastvalue is not initially defined, I am also not certain that the last value would work because there will be different values before the _i_ break which would not be == lastvalue but still need to be printed

Comment: @MrHelpme I am sorry, I still dont understand that lastValue if statement, do you want to save the last value before the loop broke, or do you want to get the last value in the items list?

Comment: lastvalue will get saved before the loop restarts, but the loop should only restart if the new value is the same as the old value, and the _n'th_ number has not been reached yet

Comment: @MrHelpme What do you mean by the loop restarts? I think the best way for some one to help you, would be if you printed required output for a certain input.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added one

Comment: @MrHelpme Hey, try what I wrote, and if you have questions let me know.